# How do you embed a YouTube video at a specific time into an Anki Card

Tags: youtube, anki

I would like to create Anki cards for studying [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cC0ARsj36_8).

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206812/how-do-you-embed-a-youtube-video-into-an-anki-card) on how to embed a Youtube video. The problem is that I would like to study specific phrases of the dialogs involved. So what I would like to do is to embed a youtube video into an Anki card but starting from a specific time, let's say 5:03. I really do not know how to do it. I would not like to download the video and cut it because I have read it violates the rules of Youtube.

Comment: The accepted answer of the question you linked already address this.